# when I try to render tags I get Wallpaper.Wallpaper.None

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-taggit

views.py

```
def download(request, wallpaper_name):
try:
    wallpaper = Wallpaper.objects.get(name=wallpaper_name)
    similar_wallpapers = wallpaper.tags.similar_objects()[:2]

except Exception as exc:
    wallpaper = None
    similar_wallpapers = None
    messages.error = (request, 'Sorry! data does not exist')

context = {'wallpaper': wallpaper, 'similar_wallpapers': similar_wallpapers}
return render(request, 'Wallpaper/download.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Tags(models.Model):
tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.tag



class Wallpaper(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField('date published', null=True)
    resolution = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    Device_Choices = [
        ('PC', 'pc'),
        ('mobile', 'mobile')
    ]
    Devices = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=Device_Choices, default= 'PC')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Wallpaper/Images/', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

download.html

```html
<div class="tag">
    <h3>Tags</h3>
    <ul>

        <li>{{wallpaper.tags}}</li>

    </ul>
    
</div>
```

I want all the tags of that particular wallpaper to be rendered

and if possible please tell me if there is any other way to handle tags, because using taggit its very difficult i am getting manny errors

Answer (score 0):

Tags are a many-to-many relation so you need to use `.all` in your template to get them. However, this will just show you the queryset, so you need to loop through them to render their names:

```html
<ul>
{% for tag in wallpaper.tags.all %}
    <li>{{ tag.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```